# My react routing is rendering the first child...but is not rendering the second child

Tags: react-dom

my App component is rendering... but not PdfPage. When I interchange the components, PdfPage is rendering, but not App. Please help!

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { App} from './App';
import { PdfPage } from './PdfPage';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route}     from 'react-router-dom';


const routing = (  
    <>
    <Router>  
        
        <Routes>  
        <Route exact path="/" element={<App />} />
        <Route path={"/pdfPage"} element={<PdfPage />} /> 
        </Routes>
        
    </Router> 
    </> 
  );

  ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: The `exact` means your first route will only match the root.

Comment: @DBS tried removing it.. no luck

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code and it works perfectly. Just to be sure, are you accessing pdfPage by going to `localhost:3000/pdfPage` right?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. It was not in the program. I had to edit my snowpack.config.js to enable routing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).